# AndroidPlot PieChart not visible in listview

Tags: android, pie-chart, androidplot

I'm using android plot in my app. I have different "widgets" composed into a `listview`. Some of them use a pie chart. For some reason those are not visible for Android < 5.0. For Android 5.0, 6.0 and 7.0 it seems ok though. Any ideas?

P.S
Already tried to play around with c`hart.invalidate() or chart.redraw()`.

Comment: Show you code please, otherwise it impossible to help

Comment: have u tried using multidex. it may be possible thats multidex issue.

Comment: Yes, I have multidex enabled.

Comment: for the Androidplot plot element in the listview, are you specifying a fixed height for it?  a common mistake when using plots in listviews is to use "matchParent" for height, which causes a kind of chicken and egg situation.  Not sure why that would behave differently on different SDK versions, but something to double check all the same.

Comment: Nick, Thank you! `android:minWidth="150dp" android:minHeight="150dp"` did the trick for me!